# DOMDocument prevent page from loading and does not get div content

Tags: php

I am trying to retrieve the pagetitle div using DOMDocument but it is not working..

I am using iPage to host my site.

```
<div id="pagetitle">) hopefully i'm not angry"</div>
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://protein.guru/" data-layout="button_count"></div>

<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="ddddd" data-via="prtnguru">Tweet</a><br /></div><br/>

            <p>                
            <?php
            include '../rblog.php';
            ?>

<?php 
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTML($temp);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$divContent = $xpath->query('*/div[id="pagetitle"]');

echo $divContent;
?>
```

Please let me know if you have any ideas on why it is not working.

Comment: There is a [getElementById](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php) method that would likely be easier. What is your script outputting? Perhaps `$divContent` is an object, try `var_dump($divContent)` to see what it's actual value is. `DOMXPath::query` should return a `DOMNodeList` object.

Comment: Am I able to use a javascript variable within PHP? I have just started learning javascript - well now the page is loading after changing echo to var_dump. The output was " object(DOMNodeList)#5 (1) { ["length"]=> int(0) } "

Comment: it isn't javascript. DOMDocument has many of the same DOM methods built in though: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a DOMDocument method for [getElementById](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php). Here is an example using it:

```
<?php
$html ='<div id="pagetitle">) hopefully i\'m not angry"</div>
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://protein.guru/" data-layout="button_count"></div>

<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-text="ddddd" data-via="prtnguru">Tweet</a><br/>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTML($html);

$element = $dom->getElementById("pagetitle");

echo "The page title is: " . $element->textContent;
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/J4c4ob

Comment: wow very simple solution! Thanks! It is working exactly how I wanted.